# how to modify hosts list within tasks with fabric2?

Tags: python, fabric

With fabric 1.x I have a fabfile about like this :

```
from fabric.api import env

def prod():
    env.hosts += ['1.2.3.4']

def integ():
    env.hosts += ['2.3.4.5']

def doit():
    env.user = 'root'
    - do some stuff here -
```

By this way, I am able to specify my targets : to execute doit() for integration, I can do :

```
fab integ doit
```

for integration and production, I can do :

```
fab integ prod doit
```

With fabric2, I can see there no more api and one have to use Connection object but, I cannot see where I can change the current SerialGroup to add some hosts on-the-fly.

How can I port this code to fabric2 ??

Answer (score 1):

After debugging, I discovered that all "call" objects to each host have already been created before their execution : There is no use to modify a hosts list inside a tasks, the games are already set.
Nevertheless I found a workaround, one can do something like this :

```
from fabric import task, SerialGroup
hosts_to_process = []

@task
def prod(c):
    global hosts_to_process
    hosts_to_process += ['1.2.3.4']

@task
def integ(c):
    global hosts_to_process
    hosts_to_process += ['2.3.4.5']

@task
def doit(c):
    if not hasattr(c,'host'):
        group = SerialGroup(*hosts_to_process)
        for c in group:
            doit(c)
    else:
        env.user = 'root'
        - do some stuff here -
```

By this way, one can now do one of the following :

```
fab integ doit
fab integ prod doit
fab -H 3.4.5.6 doit
```